# Can an android app have two gcm registration ids generated using two different sender ids?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have integrated a third party android SDK in my app. It generates a registration id using its sender ID.

My app also generates a registration id using my app's sender Id. Two different registration ids are generated right now and both ids are valid as i can send notifications to those ids.

Will this approach cause any issues?(Like one of them becoming invalid)

Comment: It doesn't seem a problem, because SDk's are designed not infer such functions of main application, so i dont think there will be any issue.